# Add App-Tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

On IE9 there's [`msAddSiteMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff976309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ask the user if he wants to pin your site to his browser/taskbar.

Is there an equivalent or similar function to offer the user to add your site as an App-Tab on Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not an equivalent of this in Firefox.